# The code is giving Multiple Marker at this line

Tags: jakarta-mail

This line giving errors I am not able to find any clue kindly help me..??
I have added all the related jar files then also its giving error
please check code and help

```
Properties properties = System.getProperties();  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
```

Comment: What exactly are the errors? Have you imported `java.util.Properties`?

Comment: Welcome to SO, you should be more specific with your question. What is exactly the error?

Comment: Improved formatting and fixed grammar. Please add more detail to your question like manifest detail and more code